# Toggle css and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make this jQuery function work with all paragraphs? I do not want to do a function for each paragraph as this will grow dynamically. Thanks!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#alternar-respuesta1').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (jQuery('p.tit_veel').hasClass("tit_grey")) {
      jQuery('p.tit_veel').removeClass("tit_grey").addClass("tit_blue");
      jQuery('#alternar-respuesta-ej1').removeClass("fa-angle-down tit_grey").addClass("fa-angle-up tit_blue");
    } else {
      jQuery('p.tit_veel').removeClass("tit_blue").addClass("tit_grey");
      jQuery('#alternar-respuesta-ej1').removeClass("fa-angle-up tit_blue").addClass("fa-angle-down tit_grey");
    }
    jQuery('#respuesta1').toggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
#respuesta1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row mt60">
  <div id="veelges" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <p class="tit_veel tit_grey">1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit?<a class="right arrow" href="#"><i id="alternar-respuesta1" class="fa fa-angle-down tit_grey" aria-hidden="true"></a></i>
    </p>
    <div id="respuesta">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur. adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
        non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <p class="tit_veel tit_grey">1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit?<a class="right arrow" href="#"><i id="alternar-respuesta2" class="fa fa-angle-down tit_grey" aria-hidden="true"></a></i>
    </p>
    <div id="respuesta2">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur. adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
        non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <p class="tit_veel tit_grey">1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit?<a class="right arrow" href="#"><i id="alternar-respuesta3" class="fa fa-angle-down tit_grey" aria-hidden="true"></a></i>
    </p>
    <div id="respuesta3">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur. adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
        non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <p class="tit_veel tit_grey">1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit?<a class="right arrow" href="#"><i id="alternar-respuesta4" class="fa fa-angle-down tit_grey" aria-hidden="true"></a></i>
    </p>
    <div id="respuesta4">
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur. adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
        non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a problem with your html, You have an `i` element inside your `a` (link) but you close it in this order `</a></i>`. Basic your code is `<a><i></a></i>` but it should be `<a><i></i></a>`

Comment: Your jQuery code executes when an element with id `alternar-respuesta1` gets clicked. I don't see this id in your html.

Comment: sorry I did not notice now I change it

Comment: the alternar-respuesta1 is inside the <i>

Comment: Could you please describe what the function should do exactly... step by step?

Comment: I noticed the id, sorry for the oversight. In your code snippet there is nothing to click on, so i added some text: `<i id='...'>test</i>`. When i click 'test' I can see classes being removed and added. Seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest to reorganize the code.

1. Move both paragraphs into DIV
2. Treat DIV as parent element. This way you will be able to couple header/link with the text.

Press "RUN CODE SNIPPET" to see my proposal in action.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('a.right.arrow').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var p = $(this).parent();
      
      if (p.hasClass("tit_grey")) {        
        p.removeClass("tit_grey").addClass("tit_blue");
        
        //$('#alternar-respuesta-ej1').removeClass("fa-angle-down tit_grey").addClass("fa-angle-up tit_blue");
      } else {
        p.removeClass("tit_blue").addClass("tit_grey");        
        //$('#alternar-respuesta-ej1').removeClass("fa-angle-up tit_blue").addClass("fa-angle-down tit_grey");
      }
      
      var div = p.parent();      
      div.children('.paragraph-txt') .toggle('slow');
   });
    
});
```

```css
.paragraph-txt {
  display: none;
}

.tit_grey{ background: #CCC;}
.tit_blue{ background: #AAF;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row mt60">
  <div id="veelges" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
  
 <div id="respuesta1" >
  
  <p class="tit_veel tit_grey">1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit?
    <a class="right arrow" href="#">
      <i id="alternar-respuesta1" class="fa fa-angle-down tit_grey" aria-hidden="true">SHOW</i>
    </a>
  </p>
  
  <p class="paragraph-txt">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur. adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
        non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    <div id="respuesta2" >
      
      <p class="tit_veel tit_grey">1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit?<a class="right arrow" href="#"><i id="alternar-respuesta2" class="fa fa-angle-down tit_grey" aria-hidden="true">SHOW</i></a>
    </p>
    
      <p class="paragraph-txt"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur. adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
        non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
   
    
    
    <div id="respuesta3" >
     <p class="tit_veel tit_grey">1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit?<a class="right arrow" href="#"><i id="alternar-respuesta3" class="fa fa-angle-down tit_grey" aria-hidden="true">SHOW</i></a>
    </p>
    
      <p class="paragraph-txt"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur. adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
        non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    
     <div id="respuesta4" >
    <p class="tit_veel tit_grey">1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit?<a class="right arrow" href="#"><i id="alternar-respuesta4" class="fa fa-angle-down tit_grey" aria-hidden="true">SHOW</i></a>
    </p>
   
      <p class="paragraph-txt"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur. adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
        non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
The same code on JSFIDDLE -> https://jsfiddle.net/o95dq69m/3/